# Extraer datos de Json - PHP

Tags: json, php7

Tengo la información Json de la siguiente forma en MySQL

```
{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/m67smI1IIMmYzCl9axvKNULVKLr.jpg",
        "belongs_to_collection":{"id":10194,"name":"Toy Story Collection","poster_path":"/7G9915LfUQ2lVfwMEEhDsn3kT4B.jpg","backdrop_path":"/9FBwqcd9IRruEDUrTdcaafOMKUq.jpg"},
        "budget":175000000,
        "genres":[{"id":12,"name":"Adventure"},{"id":16,"name":"Animation"},{"id":35,"name":"Comedy"},{"id":10751,"name":"Family"},{"id":14,"name":"Fantasy"}],
        "homepage":"https://www.pixar.com/feature-films-toy-story-4",
        "id":301528,
        "imdb_id":"tt1979376",
        "original_language":"en",
        "original_title":"Toy Story 4",
        "overview":"Woody has always been confident about his place in the world and that his priority is taking care of his kid, whether that's Andy or Bonnie. But when Bonnie adds a reluctant new toy called \"Forky\" to her room, a road trip adventure alongside old and new friends will show Woody how big the world can be for a toy.",
        "popularity":125.276,
        "poster_path":"/w9kR8qbmQ01HwnvK4alvnQ2ca0L.jpg",
        "production_companies":[{"id":2,"logo_path":"/wdrCwmRnLFJhEoH8GSfymY85KHT.png","name":"Walt Disney Pictures","origin_country":"US"},{"id":3,"logo_path":"/1TjvGVDMYsj6JBxOAkUHpPEwLf7.png","name":"Pixar","origin_country":"US"}],"production_countries":[{"iso_3166_1":"US","name":"United States of America"}],
        "release_date":"2019-06-19",
        "revenue":519802847,
        "runtime":100,
        "spoken_languages":[{"iso_639_1":"en","name":"English"}],
        "status":"Released",
        "tagline":"Get Ready to Hit the Road",
        "title":"Toy Story 4",
        "video":false,
        "vote_average":7.6,
        "vote_count":2580,
        "credits":{"cast":[{"cast_id":6,"character":"Woody (voice)","credit_id":"577a78b8c3a368770400058f","gender":2,"id":31,"name":"Tom Hanks","order":0,"profile_path":"/xxPMucou2wRDxLrud8i2D4dsywh.jpg"},{"cast_id":66,"character":"Buzz Lightyear (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12ad92514129a2035517","gender":2,"id":12898,"name":"Tim Allen","order":1,"profile_path":"/PGLz0YLg4eB49BA6QxzHF5czxX.jpg"},{"cast_id":58,"character":"Bo Peep (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12aa9251417df40bff9f","gender":1,"id":8873,"name":"Annie Potts","order":2,"profile_path":"/eryXT84RL41jHSJcMy4kS3u9y6w.jpg"},{"cast_id":63,"character":"Jessie (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12ac9251412fc40f59a2","gender":1,"id":3234,"name":"Joan Cusack","order":3,"profile_path":"/3jcrXcFYoSKEUvokzqrQ2UJGtw.jpg"},{"cast_id":71,"character":"Forky (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12aec3a3683bf0df729a","gender":2,"id":25147,"name":"Tony Hale","order":4,"profile_path":"/ar4uapp4w5wMkThZcqWUNMSTO8z.jpg"},{"cast_id":55,"character":"Duke Caboom (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12aa9251412fc40f599b","gender":2,"id":6384,"name":"Keanu Reeves","order":5,"profile_path":"/bOlYWhVuOiU6azC4Bw6zlXZ5QTC.jpg"},{"cast_id":60,"character":"Ducky (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12ab9251412fc40f599f","gender":2,"id":298410,"name":"Keegan-Michael Key","order":6,"profile_path":"/gqPRozx8ppAg2TSjW3ww56LnIZr.jpg"},{"cast_id":57,"character":"Bunny (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12aa9251417aa20c2425","gender":2,"id":291263,"name":"Jordan Peele","order":7,"profile_path":"/9rOEfvKUInuUpJ6MMhiC8Tch1WM.jpg"},{"cast_id":92,"character":"Gabby Gabby (voice)","credit_id":"5c918de10e0a2612f55c3d1c","gender":1,"id":110014,"name":"Christina Hendricks","order":8,"profile_path":"/fqQWrKDhOTAPjjNTHSU4tBfq5NJ.jpg"},{"cast_id":93,"character":"Giggle McDimples (voice)","credit_id":"5c918dff0e0a2612ef5c5d78","gender":1,"id":209596,"name":"Ally Maki","order":9,"profile_path":"/fZK27EmQkDTtUayLX38XhLBZE9h.jpg"},{"cast_id":94,"character":"Mr. Potato Head (voice)","credit_id":"5c9cf99792514124c5312c59","gender":2,"id":7167,"name":"Don Rickles","order":10,"profile_path":"/h5BcaDMPRVLHLDzbQavec4xfSdt.jpg"},{"cast_id":73,"character":"Slinky Dog (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12af92514129d503c75f","gender":2,"id":21485,"name":"Blake Clark","order":11,"profile_path":"/j6nhwuLKJXzHuD4zv2d3y99PcIC.jpg"},{"cast_id":62,"character":"Rex (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12ac0e0a262c999fb6d5","gender":2,"id":12900,"name":"Wallace Shawn","order":12,"profile_path":"/oGE6JqPP2xH4tNORKNqxbNPYi7u.jpg"},{"cast_id":68,"character":"Hamm (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12ad0e0a260e9e9b90e3","gender":2,"id":7907,"name":"John Ratzenberger","order":13,"profile_path":"/oRtDEOuIO1yDhTz5dORBdxXuLMO.jpg"},{"cast_id":72,"character":"Mrs. Potato Head (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12af0e0a261aaf9f52f9","gender":1,"id":61964,"name":"Estelle Harris","order":14,"profile_path":"/equDBtZgBkO7e8QKpNokDz9EbY9.jpg"},{"cast_id":75,"character":"Squeeze Toy Aliens (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12afc3a3685cbddee043","gender":2,"id":7882,"name":"Jeff Pidgeon","order":15,"profile_path":"/yLddkg5HcgbJg00cS13GVBnP0HY.jpg"},{"cast_id":59,"character":"Mr. Pricklepants (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12ab92514129a2035514","gender":2,"id":10669,"name":"Timothy Dalton","order":16,"profile_path":"/n7QJKtA7jTwGHVuL5cPkqzu7CDG.jpg"},{"cast_id":61,"character":"Trixie (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12ab0e0a266dacabaf13","gender":1,"id":109869,"name":"Kristen Schaal","order":17,"profile_path":"/rn84XtsczLSvJOWWNXLocaLx2df.jpg"},{"cast_id":70,"character":"Buttercup (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12aec3a3684f97eb1407","gender":2,"id":60074,"name":"Jeff Garlin","order":18,"profile_path":"/cBs7u7rBTvDFp5MFCnvrPeF7SI2.jpg"},{"cast_id":65,"character":"Dolly (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12ac0e0a260e9e9b90dc","gender":1,"id":5149,"name":"Bonnie Hunt","order":19,"profile_path":"/uKAfrFRZYnHFAxw53Jldbs8yIZO.jpg"},{"cast_id":74,"character":"Chuckles the Clown (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12af0e0a261aaf9f52fc","gender":2,"id":7918,"name":"Bud Luckey","order":20,"profile_path":"/pcCh7G19FKMNijmPQg1PMH1btic.jpg"},{"cast_id":103,"character":"Bonnie (voice)","credit_id":"5d066a8092514104c4bba1c0","gender":1,"id":1530558,"name":"Madeleine McGraw","order":21,"profile_path":"/wrnJbVuxcEzmsU5FukVnFmS54Xo.jpg"},{"cast_id":96,"character":"Bonnie’s Dad (voice)","credit_id":"5d06691a92514163d1bfb253","gender":2,"id":19487,"name":"Jay Hernandez","order":22,"profile_path":"/phKVHS0PEAoWxqiYDJKL2K82ZX0.jpg"},{"cast_id":106,"character":"Andy Davis (voice)","credit_id":"5d0a59a30e0a2628abccec25","gender":2,"id":1116442,"name":"John Morris","order":23,"profile_path":"/vYGyvK4LzeaUCoNSHtsuqJUY15M.jpg"},{"cast_id":64,"character":"Mrs. Davis (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12acc3a3685cbddee040","gender":1,"id":12133,"name":"Laurie Metcalf","order":24,"profile_path":"/oHhTbuv9eNJV4YlgizhCkZsPV0N.jpg"},{"cast_id":56,"character":"Harmony’s Mom (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12aac3a368745eeca074","gender":1,"id":4687,"name":"Patricia Arquette","order":25,"profile_path":"/2ZIZ2xIdWKZNKRcdIe60AH25c82.jpg"},{"cast_id":69,"character":"Julia Anderson (voice)","credit_id":"5c6d12ae0e0a261aaf9f52f6","gender":1,"id":24358,"name":"Lori Alan","order":26,"profile_path":"/mNfJWzuaKgkIaK7CuirXOMosd2h.jpg"},{"cast_id":95,"character":"Axel the Carnie (voice)","credit_id":"5d0668939251413f2dbdb061","gender":2,"id":19278,"name":"Bill Hader","order":27,"profile_path":"/3Z5JsyLw7YTLZgpA3FAlLmFSN9F.jpg"},{"cast_id":97,"character":"Melephant Brooks (voice)","credit_id":"5d06694792514163d1bfb2bc","gender":2,"id":14639,"name":"Mel Brooks","order":28,"profile_path":"/ndFo3LOYNCUghQTK833N1Wtuynr.jpg"},{"cast_id":98,"character":"Bitey White (voice)","credit_id":"5d0669640e0a260b0ad139af","gender":1,"id":71727,"name":"Betty White","order":29,"profile_path":"/mgajnHMGottmiuwOeIRicx9BzbD.jpg"},{"cast_id":99,"character":"Combat Carl (voice)","credit_id":"5d0669a80e0a260b0ad139de","gender":2,"id":1101,"name":"Carl Weathers","order":30,"profile_path":"/xOpDfVa83R1EdiNkWPNITfCH67e.jpg"},{"cast_id":100,"character":"Chairol Burnett (voice)","credit_id":"5d0669dc0e0a261357d0f1c9","gender":1,"id":14837,"name":"Carol Burnett","order":31,"profile_path":"/uUN23A8WtaLcItllwFADuyqF8Ci.jpg"},{"cast_id":101,"character":"Carl Reineroceros (voice)","credit_id":"5d066a180e0a260eddcd7316","gender":2,"id":1895,"name":"Carl Reiner","order":32,"profile_path":"/AtDqJQkl7dH2m19kPio3cosfbes.jpg"},{"cast_id":102,"character":"Margaret the Store Owner (voice)","credit_id":"5d066a4f0e0a266424cb6274","gender":1,"id":35515,"name":"June Squibb","order":33,"profile_path":"/2QDE0wZ9B9a4Kd2S4e9XP65agrf.jpg"},{"cast_id":104,"character":"Old Timer (voice)","credit_id":"5d066a9c0e0a26511fcb14c4","gender":2,"id":24320,"name":"Alan Oppenheimer","order":34,"profile_path":"/5UAa7wSnoh6JwiAKciCCKB9dnro.jpg"},{"cast_id":105,"character":"Duke Caboom Advert (voice)","credit_id":"5d066b9f9251413f2dbdb4d2","gender":2,"id":1237,"name":"Flea","order":35,"profile_path":"/3mvSPp8RpuuPJUuNwq9PyjFu2Ug.jpg"},{"cast_id":108,"character":"Karen Beverly (voice)","credit_id":"5d0f9cfd9251417099bdd65b","gender":0,"id":1695631,"name":"Melissa Villaseñor","order":36,"profile_path":"/144VoO4M5sU0Mn4lpTOYQFAgNVO.jpg"}],
                   "crew":[{"credit_id":"5c6ebb529251417df4101543","department":"Directing","gender":2,"id":84496,"job":"Director","name":"Josh Cooley","profile_path":"/yctxPn9Nk0ACFuf4KRUbbeYSxjT.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5c9169359251410feaa6d374","department":"Sound","gender":2,"id":7885,"job":"Original Music Composer","name":"Randy Newman","profile_path":"/w0JzfoiM25nrnxYOzosPHRq6mlE.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5c9169439251410ff6a6da2d","department":"Writing","gender":1,"id":1744241,"job":"Screenplay","name":"Stephany Folsom","profile_path":"/5OAuBOYlQOeQfexrbkT0QOWBfxi.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5c9169970e0a2612ed5bac29","department":"Writing","gender":2,"id":7,"job":"Screenplay","name":"Andrew Stanton","profile_path":"/gasNitCwepbqNcYBmDHpsCgZH0I.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5c9169ca0e0a2612fc5bb454","department":"Editing","gender":0,"id":8071,"job":"Editor","name":"Axel Geddes","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5c9169d90e0a2612fc5bb471","department":"Art","gender":2,"id":7889,"job":"Production Design","name":"Bob Pauley","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5c9169e40e0a2612f15c20be","department":"Camera","gender":0,"id":7975,"job":"Director of Photography","name":"Patrick Lin","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5c9169f89251410fe7a6c6fa","department":"Camera","gender":0,"id":7894,"job":"Director of Photography","name":"Jean-Claude Kalache","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5c916a0f0e0a2612ef5c0531","department":"Crew","gender":0,"id":2268931,"job":"Supervising Technical Director","name":"Bob Moyer","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5c916a200e0a2612f15c211e","department":"Production","gender":2,"id":7,"job":"Executive Producer","name":"Andrew Stanton","profile_path":"/gasNitCwepbqNcYBmDHpsCgZH0I.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5c916a380e0a2612ef5c0578","department":"Production","gender":2,"id":8,"job":"Executive Producer","name":"Lee Unkrich","profile_path":"/bdTCCXjgOV3YyaNmLGYGOxFQMOc.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5c916a410e0a266237593170","department":"Production","gender":2,"id":12890,"job":"Executive Producer","name":"Pete Docter","profile_path":"/r6ngPgnReA3RHmKjmSoVsc6Awjp.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5c916a4f9251410feda6b982","department":"Production","gender":0,"id":7940,"job":"Producer","name":"Jonas Rivera","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5c916a760e0a2612ef5c059e","department":"Production","gender":0,"id":8103,"job":"Producer","name":"Mark Nielsen","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5c916b120e0a2613045c477e","department":"Visual Effects","gender":2,"id":8011,"job":"Animation Supervisor","name":"Scott Clark","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5c916b1fc3a368611651f73f","department":"Visual Effects","gender":0,"id":8041,"job":"Animation Supervisor","name":"Robert H. Russ","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5d1139430e0a262177cb1726","department":"Writing","gender":2,"id":59891,"job":"Story","name":"Martin Hynes","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5d113e5b0e0a26597dcb295b","department":"Writing","gender":1,"id":80591,"job":"Story","name":"Rashida Jones","profile_path":"/jjp33eRM6oavyesW0UM6XBCxQSa.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5d1144dc9251410582b8dd70","department":"Writing","gender":1,"id":225978,"job":"Story","name":"Valerie LaPointe","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5d128415925141524dc16ef6","department":"Writing","gender":2,"id":7879,"job":"Story","name":"John Lasseter","profile_path":"/7EdqiNbr4FRjIhKHyPPdFfEEEFG.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5d129ccbc3a3681ab62224b0","department":"Writing","gender":2,"id":78500,"job":"Story","name":"Will McCormack","profile_path":"/6rYTgjY1pD26F8szmlPD2WDQO3e.jpg"},{"credit_id":"5d1f050794d8a8311641c195","department":"Sound","gender":0,"id":1212508,"job":"Foley Mixer","name":"Scott Curtis","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5d1f05320328b90010d6fe5f","department":"Sound","gender":0,"id":2030398,"job":"Foley Editor","name":"James Spencer","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5d1f054755b0c0638e6b3e05","department":"Sound","gender":0,"id":2017200,"job":"Sound Editor","name":"Qianbaihui Yang","profile_path":null},{"credit_id":"5d99673cb04605002a435184","department":"Sound","gender":0,"id":2426156,"job":"Sound Designer","name":"Ren Klyce","profile_path":null}]}}
```

en este foro para extraer genere me recomendaron el sigueinte codigo

```
$movie = json_decode($datos_movies, true);
$genres = array_map(function($gen) { return $gen['name']; }, $movie['genres']);
echo implode(' / ', $genres);
```

Tengo problemas para extraer datos de "cast" y reemplazando los valores de la siguiente forma y no me funciona

```
$movie = json_decode($datos_movies, true);
$cast = array_map(function($gen) { return $gen['cast']; }, $movie['credits']);
echo implode(' / ', $cast);
```

Deseo que me muestre "Tom Hanks / Tim Allen ....."

Saludos y muchas gracias por la ayuda es un sitio web excelente.

Ya revise la respuesta 1 en PHP 7.2 y funciona muchas gracias. Una consulta extra quiero extraer los datos de credits - crew - "Director"

Para este caso solo debería mostrar "Josh Cooley"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, quieres extraer todas los valores de la propiedad `names` que hay en los objetos.

Puedes hacerlo de  una forma mucho más simple tratando el JSON como lo que es, un objeto; accediendo al array que hay dentro de `credits->cast` y aplicando allí `array_column` para buscar la propiedad `name`. Luego, al array resultante la aplicas `implode`.

### Código:

```
#No pasamos el parámetro true, porque no hace falta. Es más claro tratarlo como objeto
$movie = json_decode($datos_movies);
#Accedemos al array que hay en cast y buscamos el valor de name
$allNames = implode(" / ",array_column($movie->credits->cast, 'name'));
echo $allNames;
```

#### Salida:

```
 Tom Hanks / Tim Allen / Annie Potts / Joan Cusack / Tony Hale / Keanu
 Reeves / Keegan-Michael Key / Jordan Peele / Christina Hendricks /
 Ally Maki / Don Rickles / Blake Clark / Wallace Shawn / John
 Ratzenberger / Estelle Harris / Jeff Pidgeon / Timothy Dalton /
 Kristen Schaal / Jeff Garlin / Bonnie Hunt / Bud Luckey / Madeleine
 McGraw / Jay Hernandez / John Morris / Laurie Metcalf / Patricia
 Arquette / Lori Alan / Bill Hader / Mel Brooks / Betty White / Carl
 Weathers / Carol Burnett / Carl Reiner / June Squibb / Alan
 Oppenheimer / Flea / Melissa Villaseñor
```

---

### P.D.:

Nótese que este procedimiento es válido también para los géneros:

```
$movie = json_decode($datos_movies);
$allGenres = implode(" / ",array_column($movie->genres, 'name'));
echo $allGenres;
```

#### Salida:

```
Adventure / Animation / Comedy / Family / Fantasy
```

Comment: Ya revise en PHP 7.2 y funciona muchas gracias. un consulta extra quiero extraer los datos de credits - crew - "Director" Para este caso solo debería mostrar "Josh Cooley"

Comment: @MarcosAmadorBonilla puedes obtenerlo así: `$firstCrew = $movie->credits->crew[0]->name; echo $firstCrew;`  si es que el criterio de búsqueda es obtener **el nombre del primer elemento que hay en `crew`**.

Comment: Si me muestra la información del primer nombre que aparece en crew. lo malo es que no siempre el primer nombre es el del director. ocupo que muestre el del director.

Comment: @MarcosAmadorBonilla en ese caso puedes hacer algo así: `$allDirectors = array_filter(
    $movie->credits->crew,
    function ($o) {
        return  $o->job == "Director";
    }
);

echo $allDirectors[0]->name;` Esto te devolverá un array con todos los objetos cuyo `job` sea igual a `Director`. Si son varios puedes usar `implode` como en los otros casos para mostrarlos separados por `/`. Aquí, suponiendo que es uno solo, se usa el índice `0` en la lectura.

Comment: Hola Muchas gracias por su tiempo y por compartir su conocimiento, revise con la solución propuesta y no me funciona me da un resultado en blanco, espero alguna otra idea de como mostrar "Director". Saludos

Comment: @MarcosAmadorBonilla lo he probado con el JSON de tu pregunta y me funciona perfectamente, me imprime `Josh Cooley`. Si no funciona es porque algo escribiste mal o porque el array tiene otra estructura. En cualquier caso, este sería objeto de una nueva pregunta donde tendrías también, quizá, varias propuestas de solución.

Comment: ya esta funcionando lo que hice fue remplazar == por = y me quedo de esta forma.
**[$allDirectors = array_filter( $movie->credits->crew, function ($o) { return $o->job = "Director"; } ); echo $allDirectors[0]->name;]**

Comment: Buenos días. algún consejo para limitar "credits->cast" a que muestre un máximo de 10 "name". hay algunas movies que el reparto es muy grande. Ejemplo [**Tom Hanks / Tim Allen / Annie Potts / Joan Cusack / Tony Hale / Keanu
 Reeves / Keegan-Michael Key / Jordan Peele / Christina Hendricks /
 Ally Maki**]

Comment: @MarcosAmadorBonilla has preguntado varias cosas interesantes y te he ido respondiendo, ¿Por qué mejor no planteas una nueva pregunta con esta nueva duda? Así otros la pueden ver y darte más ideas y SO se enriquece. Si no las respuestas quedan casi invisibles en un comentario. Además la naturaleza del sitio indica que se abra una pregunta por cada duda diversa, aunque sea sobre el mismo código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo asi sera. Saludos

Comment: @MarcosAmadorBonilla si la respuesta dada aquí ha resuelto el problema planteado **originalmente**, no olvides marcar la pregunta como resuelta. Saludos.